# Simplest way for return/echo in function (shorthand IF)

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this function in my class. Default it should echo value, but also return value to variable by using optional parameter.

```
public function test($return = false) {

    $value = 'demo123';

    if ($return) {
        return $value; // optional
    } else {
        echo $value; // default
    }

}
```

Is there any way to make this "if" shorter, in one line (because I have a lot of functions with this so I can save many lines).

I tried ternary operators, but I don't know if I can use them in this somehow.

What's the best, correct, beauty way to do this return/echo function?

Comment: lines are not expensive, programmers time is

Comment: `$return?return $value:echo $value`

Comment: @Steve That's why you omit the dot at the end of the sentence? ;)

Comment: Thamilan I tried this before. unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not just always return the value? If the code that calls the function doesn't need it, can't it just call the function without assigning its return to anything?

Comment: Weird to echo inside a method. I think you really don't need the echo, I think you really can return a null value instead.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I think the $return specifies what is calling the function. If it's an AJAX call then echo the result as a response, if it's PHP calling the function then return the result.

Comment: @AustinSchmidt Ok, but echoing directly through a method I think there's not the best way. I think is the worst way, in fact.

Comment: What's wrong with echoing your response? How else would you respond to an AJAX call, return doesn't work for that.

Comment: `return` immediately exits a function, so you can do `if($return) return $value; echo $value;` In the first case, the $return will exit the function, and the echo statement won't be read. In the second case, the return doesn't happen, leaving the program to continue on to the echo statement.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Well, that's exactly what `var_export()` does... :)

Comment: @KeithTyler what????

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php : `mixed var_export ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )` ... "**return**
If used and set to TRUE, var_export() will return the variable representation instead of outputting it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lines are not expensive, so reducing lines of code is not a particularly useful goal, especially if it reduces readability.

However, you can remove the else clause, as return will, well, return!

```
public function test($return = false)
{
    $value = 'demo123';

    if ($return) {
        return $value; // optional
    }
    echo $value; // default
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this because of code replication, then I'd pass all results through another function that would evaluate $return.

```
private function returnOrEcho($value, $return){
  if($return) return $value;
  echo $value;
}

public function test($return = false){
  $value = 'demo123';
  return $this->returnOrEcho($value, $return);
}

public function test2($return = false){
  $value = 'demo456';
  return $this->returnOrEcho($value, $return);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is would I would do in your case. It would be only 1 line of code at the end of each function.

```
public function test($return = false)
{
    $value = 'demo123';

    return returnMe($return, $value);
}

private function returnMe($return = false, $value){
    if ($return) {
        return $value;
    }else{
        echo $value;
        return false;
    }
}
```